# Support method assignTimestampsAndWatermarks in KeyedStream of Flink DataStream

Tags: windows, flink-streaming

we are using flink to process data from kafka topic, the data in kafka topic comes from massive IoT devices, we hash those devices into different partition based on hash code of device ID, so each partition has event data from many devices, and those event data contains "timestamp", "value", "deviceID" and so on. we want to use flink to do streaming process of those data, and our rule is to calculate the average value in 20 seconds for each device. but this is one problem, since all device share same timestamp and watermark generator, and each device has clock skew, the skew maybe very large, so this breaks rule of strictly ascending event time, if we can support assignTimestampsAndWatermarks in KeyedStream, then all those problem could be resolved.

Sample code:

```
DataStream<Order> timestampStream = orderStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator());

KeyedStream<Order, String> keyStream =  timestampStream.keyBy(new KeySelector<Order,String>() {
    public String getKey(Order value) throws Exception {
        return value.getId();
    }
});
keyStream.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(20)));
```